# Ember 2.0 alternative for transitionTo since its deprecated

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

So I am trying to make a component named 'fsol-app-btn' that *is* an A tag link.
The first thing I did was change the tagName in the component.js So it properly renders on the page as an A tag.

Here is the component.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['btn', 'btn-app'],
    tagName: 'a',
    num: false,
    color: 'aqua',
    route: 'dashboard',
    mouseDown: function() {
        console.log('f'+this.get('route'));
        //this.transtionTo(this.get('route'));
        this.sendAction('action', this.get('route'));
    }
});
```

Here is the component's template.hbs:

```
{{#if num}}
    <span class="badge bg-{{color}}">{{num}}</span>
{{/if}}
<i class="fa fa-{{icon}}"></i>{{title}}
```

Now here it is in the html:

```
 {{fsol-app-btn icon='bullhorn' title='Notifications' route='index' num='3' color='yellow'}}
```

`icon`, `title`, `color`, and `num` all work and are just for styling so this one component can be used for any kind of button I want.

But the button's main functionality is to **click and do something, in this case I want it to go to a route, such as a `link-to` helper would.** I tried passing a `route='name of route'` and then on `mouseDown` call `this.transtionTo(this.get('route'))`;

But I get a deprecated warning and it doesn't work.

So how do i do this? 
btw: I also tried `this.sendAction()` and in this case I had an action called 'clicked' defined like so:

```
{{fsol-app-btn icon='bullhorn' action="clicked" title='Notifications' route='index' num='3' color='yellow'}}
```

But then I got an error saying that my fsol-app-btn's parent component had no action handler for: clicked

I tried making routes all over the place in locations I thought would catch the action but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using a `link-to`? It isn't quite clear from your question. There is a [routing service RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/95) being currently implemented that would be of use to you.

Comment: you also need `transitionToRoute` when you are transitioning from a controller and not a route.

Answer (score 0):

@locks is right.  You want to use a link-to helper and specify the classes to make it behave like a button per your code sample.

The link-to supports inline and block invocations, so you should be able to put your badge, text, etc. inside the link-to helper.

Just add something like the following in your component's template.

`{{#link-to route classNames="btn btn-app"}}
    {{#if num}}
      <span class="badge bg-{{color}}">{{num}}</span>
    {{/if}}
    <i class="fa fa-{{icon}}"></i>{{title}}
{{/link-to}}`

Applicable Ember Api - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_link-to

Comment: The main reason is then when it renders the page I have an 'a' tag inside an 'a' tag like this: 
<a id="ember2423" class="ember-view btn btn-app">
     <a id="ember2424" href="/dashboard" class="ember-view">
        ....
     </a>
</a>

Also then the button's css is all off and doesnt render correctly, plus its silly to have double 'a' tag. Thats why I changed the tagName of the component to be an 'a' tag

Comment: A few options:

* You could leave the tagName as the default, 'div'  
  

* You can technically set the tagName to '', but it's not well supported  


* Components have implicit 'click' handlers.  You can implement this and invoke a closure action which is sourced from a route which has access to `transitionTo`.  


* There's also ember-route-action-helper that lets you call an action on an explicit route.  Here again, you would then have access to the transitionTo method